# ASP.NET Core 2.0 Assembly.Load - System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, autofac, assembly-loading

I have a solution with ASP.NET Core project and Windows service project plus data access and business dll. I use autofac for dependency injection. In the windows service project, I load dlls that contain autofac modules as follows:

```
    Assembly.Load("EnterpriseDirectory.Data");
    Assembly.Load("EnterpriseDirectory.Web.Business");
    builder.RegisterAssemblyModules(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
        .Where(w => w.GetName().Name == "EnterpriseDirectory.Data"
        || w.GetName().Name == "EnterpriseDirectory.Web.Business").ToArray());
```

Modules are properly registered and everything works. But if I do the same in the ASP.NET Core application, the assemblies are loaded with the following exception and modules are not registered:

```
DefinedTypes = '((System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly)ass).DefinedTypes' threw an exception of type 'System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException'
```

I tried wrapping the Assembly.Load method into the try catch block, but no exception was captured. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What kind of assembly is it? `netstandard2.x`? or `net46x`? If later, does it use any API unavailable to `netstandard2.x`? If yes, you can't use it. Only `netstandard2.0` assemblies can be used with .NET Core 2.0 and `net4xx` **only** if they **don't use any apis unavailable in .NET Standard**. If your assemblies use API unavailable in .NET Standard, they won't work with .NET Core. Only in ASP.NET Core targeting .NET Framework 4.6.1, but it only runs on Windows then

Comment: The problem was that NuGet Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection has a lower version of Autofac in dependencies than the one I have in my data access layer.

Comment: If you require Autofac in your data access layer, chances are you are doing it wrong. The IoC container should only be referenced in the main application. If you want to modularize your application (where your composition root is) you should rather use `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection` (optimally in a different assembly than your data access layer classes).

Comment: Web assembly has a Business Layer reference. Business Layer has a Data Layer reference. How do I register Repositories, UnitOfWork, EF Context, etc. into the IoC container without referencing the Data Layer in to the Web assembly and doing all the classes public? I have all classes internal and only interfaces are public.